# Extend bluetooth timer before disconnect on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, speakers

I set up my Trusty desktop as a bluetooth speaker and I'm able to connect to it from something like a smartphone or my iPad. When the connection is confirmed, I open Netflix or Spotify but often by then the connection is already dead. That or it attempts to work and it ultimately disconnects.

There are a few times when I can start playing some music fast enough that the bluetooth stops dropping, but that's easily 10% of the times.

Is there any way to tweak the timeout in Ubuntu so that it gives the device plenty of time to start transmitting sound before it kicks it out?

Depending on the device sometimes starting an app producing sound in the background is an option to avoid disconnection, on some devices this might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout settings can be configured in files found in /etc/bluetooth/ .
I would start with the main.conf file first.

Comment: Might be more helpful if you could specify which files are to be amended and how they should be amended.